# how to avoid invoking free() before each "return "

Tags: c, free

I'm facing a problem of free() what has been malloc(). Is there a way to avoid writing free(p) multiple times in the following code?

```
char *p = (char*) (malloc(100 * sizeof(char)));
if (A)
{
    free(p);
    p=NULL;
    return -1;
}
a++;
if (B)
{
    free(p);
    p=NULL;
    return -1;
}
b++;
if (C)
{
    free(p);
    p=NULL;
    return -1;
}
free(p);
p=NULL;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This'll  likely be unpopular but you could use a single `goto` label for cleanup at the end of a function

```
    char *p = malloc(100);
    int ret = -1;
    if (A)
        goto cleanup;
    a++;
    if (B)
        goto cleanup;
    b++;
    if (C)
        goto cleanup;
    ret = 0; /* success */
cleanup:
    free(p);
    return ret;
```

Note that I've made some other small changes to your code

- removed the cast from the return from `malloc`
- removed the use of `sizeof(char)` from your allocation calculation.  This is guaranteed to be 1
- removed NULLing of `p` at the end of your function.  Its about to go out of scope so it doesn't matter that it points to freed memory

Comment: Or alternatively (yet less favourably) create a thin wrapper that does nothing but allocation and free.....

Comment: I was always using this mechanism because it's clean and effecient and improves readabillity as well as avoiding errors and always I got told by excessive OO freaks that goto is still bad. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about a goto. In cases like this of resource reclamation it isn't a bad thing to do and due to not repeating code is actually good from a DRY point of view.

```
// set res and then 
if (A) { goto cleanup;}
a++;
if (B) { goto cleanup;}
...
cleanup:
 free(p);
 p = NULL;
 return res;
```

Answer (score 2):

It always depends on what you want to put in evidence... Having a lot of return makes in evidence the early-out and sometimes simplifies the reading. However, in some cases, it forces to duplicate lots of code. I personnally prefer having a single return point in a method and having the logic made through nested ifs.

A little more complex to read, but you are sure that you don't forget a free...

```
int retCode = -1;

if (!A)
{
    a++;
    if (!B)
    {
        b++;
        if (!C)
        {
            retCode = 0;
        }
    }
}

free(p);
p=NULL;
return retCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `goto`. This is one of the typical use cases tailor cut for `goto` in C.

```
if(condition) 
{ 
    goto cleanup;
}

cleanup:
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *p = malloc(100);

// Step 1: evaluate the conditions
int aTrue = A ? 1 : 0;
int bTrue = B ? 1 : 0;
int cTrue = C ? 1 : 0;
free(p);
p = NULL;

// Step 2: evaluate the consequences
if (aTrue) return -1;
a++;
if (bTrue) return -1;
b++;
if (cTrue) return -1;

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
char *p = (char*) (malloc(100 * sizeof(char)));

if (!A) {
    a++;
    if (!B)
        b++;
}

free(p);
p=NULL;

if (A || B || C)
    return -1;

return 0;
```

Comment: I think the second `if` should be be `if (!B && !A)` as in the original code it only got to `b++` if !A ...